# Migrate from WSS 3.0 to SharePoint 2010 Enterprise

Tags: wss-3.0, migration

I need to upgrade my existing WSS 3.0 environment to SharePoint 2010.

I need to know that whether jumping directly to SP 2010 is possible ?

If yes, Can ypu please list the process of migration?

Thanks!

-saumil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to upgrade directly from WSS 3.0 to SharePoint Server 2010 (as in **not** Foundation) using db-attach.

Read more [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2010/07/19/upgrade-to-sharepoint-server-2010-from-other-versions-or-products.aspx) on that specific upgrade path

Also beside the points by James on upgrading customisations, be sure to read the upgrade planning documents on [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730260.aspx). Remember that upgrade more often than not is an iterative process where you do alot of trial upgrades before the actual upgrade.

Also a shameless plug to my [whitepaper](http://sites.wizdim.com/andersrask/sharepoint-2010/whitepaper-on-sharepoint-upgrade/) on upgrade

Comment: exactlly wat i was lukin for

Comment: your whitepaper is from SP2007 ... may I assume that the process is same for WSS 3.0 ?

Comment: the whitepaper is generic, yes. Since WSS is a simpler product migrating should prove easier than a full MOSS solution where migration path for services and my sites should be considered as well

Comment: thats really great paper... thanks...will update here when I am done with it....

Answer (score 1):

Yup, entirely possible to upgrade to WSS3 to SharePoint 2010.

I assume you want to stick to Foundation, but you  may want to upgrade to Server. (2010 Foundation is pretty much WSS4).

Do some background research on how to upgrade, and what options you have, on the TechNet site:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee517215

Things to note: What customisations you have made to your environment: What custom/third party Features you have installed, what pages you've customised with SharePoint Designer, what custom code you might be running.

Keep an eye out for the Pre-upgrade check articles on that site I linked to above.

You'll also have to make sure you have hardware capable of SP2010 (see System Requirements), and that your client browsers are running IE8. If not, make sure this is part of your migration strategy.

Comment: great info. thx james